# MySQL - Get a value from column through ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with the following structure:

```
id  msg
1  'Hello'
2  'Bye'
```

and I need to get "msg" value for the "id".

This is my try:

```
$text = mysql_query("SELECT msg FROM text WHERE text (id) ='$msg_num'");
```

But it doesn't work :(
Do you have suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

remove `text`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT msg FROM text WHERE id ='$msg_num'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $text = $row['msg'];  
}
```

your code is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` Please read the article below,

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: `mysql_query` returns a resource and not the text of `msg`. You need to fetch if you want the text value.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
mysql_query("SELECT msg FROM text WHERE text (id) ='$msg_num'");
```

To

```
mysql_query("SELECT msg FROM text WHERE id ='$msg_num'");
```

This type of query can be cause of [MySQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection) attacks.. so good to use to stop for 1st order injection using prepared statements.

1) Mysqli

2) PDO

Comment: thanks. I get something like "Resource id #15" and I need the value inside. Suggestions?

Comment: you need to use mysql_fetch_array() to get data from Resource

Comment: use the mysql_fetch_array($result)

Answer (score 2):

```
select id from text where id = '$msg_num'
```

The difference in this query is that it selects the column. There are no column named 'msg', thats the value.

edit: Sorry, read the table wrong (sideways).

Answer (score 1):

Bad syntax.

```
$text = mysql_query("SELECT msg FROM text WHERE text (id) ='$msg_num'");
```

Should be:

```
$text = mysql_query("SELECT msg FROM text WHERE id='$msg_num'");
```

You can use `mysql_error()` to diagnose things like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = mysql_query("SELECT msg FROM text WHERE id ='$msg_num'") or die(mysql_error());
```